Batch editing StyleSheets in Qt Designer
I have designed a GUI within QtDesigner. It uses various components such as QLineEdit, QTextEdit, QDateEdit, QComboBox etc. All of these elements have their own individual Stylesheet that I have assigned them by right-clicking on the element and then clicking 'Change styleSheet. . .'
I am now wanting to update the overall style of the GUI with certain colours being replaced. Is there a way to batch-edit Stylesheets for all elements in one go? I know I can click multiple of the same element type and alter that stylesheet which works to change the overall style for those selected items but I have multiple pages and so it seems impossible to select all of the same type of element and one time to do any type of batch editing.
I have tried to create a style.qss file and load it into my Python application but this didn't work correctly either and caused other parts of the application to be displayed incorrectly and so would end up making the process longer rather than being easier.
Any help or assistance anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

The Object Inspector can be used to select groups of elements by Ctrl+clicking the names. Alternatively, just open the ui file in a text editor and do a find and replace on the relevant colours. The qss syntax for colours is fairly easy to match. If you haven't used the same format everywhere, now might be a good time to normalise things to make the task easier for next time.
